# Nginx regex server name capturing too many urls

Tags: regex, nginx, server-name

Hello i am trying to configure an nginx web server to serve different frameworks from different subdomains. As well as serving a site on the main domain. 
For example

- example.com - serves the main website
- site1.wp.example.com - serves a wordpress website
- site2.ci.example.com - serves a codeigniter website
- site3.la.example.com - serves a laravel website

The problem i am having is this capture is capturing the example.com address:

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<vhost>.+)\.wp\.example\.com$;
```

This is shown in the error logs

```
"/var/www//web" existence failed (2: No such file or directory) while logging request, 
client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, 
server: ~(www\.)?(?<vhost>.+)\.wp\.example\.com$, 
request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", 
host: "example.com"
```

I thought that .+ meant you had to match 1 or more ?

Comment: Dunno anything about nginx, but your regex matches only strings ending with `.wp.example.com`. Is the `.wp` in the beginning really intended? That will **only** match the *wordpress* site.

Comment: Is it also the default domain? There is always a default domain and unless you have defined one, the first server block will be used.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear enough. This regex is capturing example.com somehow. I'm not a nginx wizard but i thought servername directives decided what server block is used.
For example my example.com block has 
server_name example.com;